# How can i change permissions of a USB Stick(pendrive) in Ubuntu?

Tags: security, ubuntu, permissions, chmod, chown

I am working on a security tool for Ubuntu in which I want to remove all permissions for a pendrive when i insert it into my system and ask for a password and then when i enter the right password then again set all permission to the device.But I don't know How can i do this(remove all permissions of a pendrive) using shell commands?

I have already tried these commands but these are not helpful for me:

```
sudo chown user:user /media/name_of_drive -R
sudo chmod 777 user:user /media/name_of_drive -R
```

Well,My OS is Ubuntu-16.04 LTS.

Github link of my project is:https://github.com/beNitinhere/Ubuntu-Antivirus

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
 $ sudo mount /dev/sda2/media/name_of_drive -t ntfs -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007,auto,locale=en_EN.UTF-8
```

`-t` is the key indicating the type of the file system, in this case it is `ntfs`.

`-o` sets the mount options. For home systems, probably, it makes no sense, but for self-education, you can only register access to yourself. To do this, enter the terminal:

`$ id`

and get the values `uid` and `gid` in the output. This is the `id` of the user that is logged in the system, and the `id` of his group. They are entered as options after `-o`.

`umask` is the permissions for files/folders. Differs from `chmod`:

```
 0 : read, write and execute
 1 : read and write
 2 : read and execute
 3 : read only
 4 : write and execute
 5 : write only
 6 : execute only
 7 : no permissions
```

Accordingly, the first digit - for the user, the second - for his group, the third - for all others.

You can do this (but then all users will have access rights to read-write-executable):

`sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/name_of_drive -t ntfs -o rw,exec,auto,locale=en_EN.UTF-8`

Comment: mount: can't find /dev/sdb/media/username/16GB in /etc/fstab
I got this error.

Comment: sorry, I missed the space `sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/....`  what file system on pendrive?

Comment: Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.  Now I got this error @Alex_Krug

Comment: Tabel which you provide is also wrong.https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-chmod-numeric-permissions-notation-command/  This is the right one i think.

Comment: NO. Right link this https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html (by the way, from the same site:)

Comment: `sudo umount /dev/sdb` and mount it with necessary permissions

Comment: by the way, very useful https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15451#p72947

Comment: well, does the `mount` with `umask` work? With permission codes, you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: ya these are working but still i got this error Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

Comment: but if done  - `sudo umount /dev/sdb` and mount it with necessary permissions? disable autonount flash drive function